# javascript dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with JavaScript dynamic input fields. I have three fields, one with a number and two with `a` & `b`. My problem is displaying the `b` input field under the `a` input field.

My code:

```html
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function addRowToTable()
{
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
    var iteration = lastRow;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

    // left cell
    var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration);
    cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

    // right cell
    var cellRight1 = row.insertCell(1);
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'text';
    el.name = 'element_45_1' + iteration;
    el.id = 'element_45_1' + iteration;
    el.size = 40;

    //el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;
    cellRight1.appendChild(el);

    // right cell
    var cellRight2 = row.insertCell(2);
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'text';
    el.name = 'element_45_2' + iteration;
    el.id = 'element_45_2' + iteration;
    el.size = 40;

    //el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;
    cellRight2.appendChild(el);

    // right cell
    var cellBottom3 = row.insertCell(3);
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = 'text';
    el.name = 'element_45_12' + iteration;
    el.id = 'element_45_12' + iteration;
    el.size = 40;

    //el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;
    cellBottom3.appendChild(el); 
}

function removeRowFromTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
</script>

<form action="tableaddrow_nw.html" method="get">
   <table width="540" border="1" id="tblSample">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Sample table</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="8">1</td>
      <td width="240">
        <input type="text" name="element_45_1"
               id="element_45_1" size="40" />
      </td>
      <td width="20">
        <div1>
          a.&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="element_45_2"
                 id="element_45_2" size="40" />
        </div1>
      </td>
      <td width="20">
        b.&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="element_45_12"
               id="element_45_12" size="40" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRowToTable();" />
  <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRowFromTable();" />
</p>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you mean by displaying b input field under an input field?

Comment: Oh! thanks for your quick response. Well, the thing is I you had time running the code you would have notice the layout of the input field. The code works fine, but I want to display the input fields named as a & b as mentioned before, to align under the input field A vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: You did the magic mate. It works the way I wanted, but slightly error, when adding new input fields the first block for No. 1 displays ok, the problem comes on displaying second block for No. 2. What it did it squeezing the second block on far right, instead of aligning together with first block. Would you be able to rectify that error Pleaseeee!

Comment: @user2018039: May I know to whom you are talking!! I mean which answer works correct for you: mine one or of Harry? So that either of us can proceed further to help you.

Comment: @Aayushi Jain: both answers works fine now. For some reasons, I had alter the table so that it will appear as follow: First, there are two columns on that table named Forest Name and Village Name. At the bottom of both columns mention there are two submit buttons for each column. I want to user to add forest name on the input field as she/he wish when click on Add Forest button as it works now. And I want same user to add more village name on village input field as she/he wish. My question comes on how would I add input field on village name column starting with 1,2,3,4. instead of alphabetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to dynamically add a row which has the Iteration Count as first data-cell (td), one input box as second cell and two input boxes placed one below the other as the third cell, you can try the following piece of code.

```
// right cell
var cellRight2 = row.insertCell(2);

var textNode = document.createTextNode('a');
cellRight2.appendChild(textNode);

var el1 = document.createElement('input');
el1.type = 'text';
el1.name = 'element_45_2' + iteration;
el1.id = 'element_45_2' + iteration;
el1.size = 40;
cellRight2.appendChild(el1); 

var textNode = document.createTextNode('b');
cellRight2.appendChild(textNode);
var el2 = document.createElement('input');
el2.type = 'text';
el2.name = 'element_45_12' + iteration;
el2.id = 'element_45_12' + iteration;
el2.size = 40;

//el.onkeypress = keyPressTest;

cellRight2.appendChild(el2);
```

---

Based on your response, I think this is what you are looking for.

```
function addMoreVillageNames(){
  rowNumber = (this.id).substring((this.id.length)-1, this.id.length); //to get Row Number where one more input needs to be added.

  var parentCell = this.parentNode;
  var inputCount = parentCell.getElementsByTagName('label').length; //to get the count of input fields present already
  var newFieldNo = inputCount + 1; //input current count by 1 to dynamically set next number for the new field

  parentCell.removeChild(this); //temporarily remove the add village button to insert the new field before it
  var lineBreak = newElement('br');
  parentCell.appendChild(lineBreak); //add a line break after the first field

  var el_label = newElement('label');
  el_label.for = 'village_text_' + rowNumber + '_' + newFieldNo;
  var el_labelValue = newFieldNo + ' ';
  var textNode = newTxt(el_labelValue);
  el_label.appendChild(textNode);
  parentCell.appendChild(el_label); //create and add label

  var el_input = newElement('input');
  el_input.type = 'text';
  el_input.name = 'village_text_' + rowNumber + '_' + newFieldNo;
  el_input.id = 'village_text_' + rowNumber + '_' + newFieldNo;
  el_input.size = 40;
  parentCell.appendChild(el_input); //create and add input field

  var el_btn = newElement('input'); //add the village name add button again
  el_btn.type = 'button';
  el_btn.name = 'village_btn_' + rowNumber;
  el_btn.id = 'village_btn_' + rowNumber;
  el_btn.value = 'Add Village_' + rowNumber;
  el_btn.addEventListener('click',addMoreVillageNames, false);
  parentCell.appendChild(el_btn);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response on my question. Well I did try to work on your sample code and it did work great. All I wanted as mentioned on the question has been answered perfectly. One thing I am stuck on is I wanted the first row for Forest Name field input and Village Name field input to appear when I run the working sample, instead of clicking the button to get the first row of input field to appear. Additionally, if possible to fix the Remove button for village column work. Everything else are ok, just that little alteration. I appreciate your work.

Comment: This is great it works like charm. Thanks for your help and contribution to others.

Comment: I just need to add rows on question you had answered before. I am stuck somehow cause the rows are added but can't figure out how to increment them. Help.

Comment: @RonnieNasso It would be better if you open another question rather than comment on this thread itself because that way your question is open for a lot more people to contribute. Post the code and the place where you are stuck/get an error in the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowspan` for making the `a` and `b` in same row.

```
<tr>
      <td width="8" rowspan="2">1</td>
      <td width="240" rowspan="2">
        <input type="text" name="element_45_1"
               id="element_45_1" size="40" />
      </td>
      <td width="20">
        <div1>
          a.&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="element_45_2"
                 id="element_45_2" size="40" />
        </div1>
        b.&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="element_45_12"
               id="element_45_12" size="40" />
      </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the working fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47wqF/)